# How can I center table headers with multicolumns?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, header

I'm trying to center all headers, including the one spanning accros multiple columns. I can't seem to find a solution. I'm also heaving problems with breaking the long headers three lines.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
\toprule
\thead{PK} & \thead{Nenn-\\ dicke [mm]} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Messung [mm]}      & \thead{Mittel-\\ wert [mm]}  & \thead{Standard-\\ abweichung [mm]} & \thead{Abwei-\\ chung [\%]} \\
\cmidrule(r){3-7}
    &               & 1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    &                    &                           &                 \\
\midrule
201 & 2             & 2,04 & 2,05 & 2,04 & 2,04 & 2,05 & 2,044              & 0,0049                  & 2,50          \\
202 & 2             & 2,05 & 2,06 & 2,03 & 2,03 & 2,06 & 2,046              & 0,0136                  & 3,00          \\
203 & 2             & 2,03 & 2,04 & 2,02 & 2,05 & 2,05 & 2,038              & 0,0117                  & 2,50          \\
204 & 2             & 2,02 & 2,01 & 2,03 & 2,01 & 2,05 & 2,024              & 0,0150                  & 2,50          \\
205 & 2             & 2,02 & 2,01 & 2,02 & 2,03 & 2,01 & 2,018              & 0,0075                  & 0,50          \\
206 & 2             & 2,04 & 2,06 & 2,10 & 2,05 & 2,03 & 2,056              & 0,0242                  & 1,50          \\
\midrule
401 & 4             & 4,30 & 4,27 & 4,31 & 4,30 & 4,31 & 4,298              & 0,0147                  & 7,75          \\
402 & 4             & 4,26 & 4,28 & 4,31 & 4,31 & 4,25 & 4,282              & 0,0248                  & 6,25          \\
403 & 4             & 4,30 & 4,20 & 4,29 & 4,30 & 4,33 & 4,284              & 0,0441                  & 8,25          \\
\midrule
601 & 6             & 6,61 & 6,72 & 6,63 & 6,66 & 6,55 & 6,634              & 0,0561                  & 9,17         \\
602 & 6             & 6,77 & 6,61 & 6,83 & 6,65 & 6,75 & 6,722              & 0,0806                  & 12,5         \\
603 & 6             & 6,55 & 6,71 & 6,58 & 6,68 & 6,59 & 6,622              & 0,0618                  & 9,83         \\
\bottomrule   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The "Messung" is centred this way, what's your problem with it? Also, when you're using `\thead{foo\\bar}` this sets up one cell, which consists of two rows, so you won't get those down to the table row below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \newcommand{\shead}[1]{\smash{\makecell[b]{#1}}}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{10}{c} }
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Messung [mm]} \\
    \cmidrule(r){3-7}
    PK & \shead{Nenn-\\ dicke [mm]} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & \shead{Mittel-\\ wert [mm]} & \shead{Standard-\\ abweichung [mm]} & \shead{Abwei-\\ chung [\%]} \\
    \midrule
    201 & 2             & 2,04 & 2,05 & 2,04 & 2,04 & 2,05 & 2,044              & 0,0049                  & 2,50          \\
    202 & 2             & 2,05 & 2,06 & 2,03 & 2,03 & 2,06 & 2,046              & 0,0136                  & 3,00          \\
    203 & 2             & 2,03 & 2,04 & 2,02 & 2,05 & 2,05 & 2,038              & 0,0117                  & 2,50          \\
    204 & 2             & 2,02 & 2,01 & 2,03 & 2,01 & 2,05 & 2,024              & 0,0150                  & 2,50          \\
    205 & 2             & 2,02 & 2,01 & 2,02 & 2,03 & 2,01 & 2,018              & 0,0075                  & 0,50          \\
    206 & 2             & 2,04 & 2,06 & 2,10 & 2,05 & 2,03 & 2,056              & 0,0242                  & 1,50          \\
    \midrule
    401 & 4             & 4,30 & 4,27 & 4,31 & 4,30 & 4,31 & 4,298              & 0,0147                  & 7,75          \\
    402 & 4             & 4,26 & 4,28 & 4,31 & 4,31 & 4,25 & 4,282              & 0,0248                  & 6,25          \\
    403 & 4             & 4,30 & 4,20 & 4,29 & 4,30 & 4,33 & 4,284              & 0,0441                  & 8,25          \\
    \midrule
    601 & 6             & 6,61 & 6,72 & 6,63 & 6,66 & 6,55 & 6,634              & 0,0561                  & 9,17         \\
    602 & 6             & 6,77 & 6,61 & 6,83 & 6,65 & 6,75 & 6,722              & 0,0806                  & 12,5         \\
    603 & 6             & 6,55 & 6,71 & 6,58 & 6,68 & 6,59 & 6,622              & 0,0618                  & 9,83         \\
    \bottomrule   
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I placed the single-cell headings inside a `\smash`ed `\makecell` that is aligned at the `[b]`ottom of the cell (using the shorthand `\shead`).